# Apply user defined resolution to screen

Tags: windows, resolution

I want apply user defined resolution to my screen,
but i have a problem.

I have in nVidia control center form to define my resolution,
i can write in this what i want because after submitting driver
checks (i dont know how) for this resolution is for this monitor,
i want bypass this or set resolution by other way.

Can anyone help me?

Greetings,